# JS getElementsByTagName except the one with a specific class

Tags: javascript

I have this variable:

```
var _inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

But I want to make a new variable that will select all inputs, except the inputs that have a specific class like ".nothis".

```
var _newinputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input') && document.getElementsByClass('!nothis');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[document.querySelectorAll('input:not(.nothis)')](http://jsfiddle.net/katspaugh/DXAG5/)

Comment: This isn't supported in all browsers (IE < 8, FF < 3.5)

Comment: This particular selector isn't even supported by IE8. It seems to not recognize the `:not()` function.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var _inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var filteredInputs = [];
var re = new RegExp('\\b' + 'nothis' + '\\b');  // or any other class name
for(var i=0; i<_inputs.length;i++) {
    if (!re.test(input.className)) {   // filter out by class name
        filteredInputs.push(_inputs[i]);
    }
}
```

**Update:** Added regex match to eliminate false positives as per suggestion from [katspaugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352796/katspaugh)

Comment: Beat me to it... but what happens if the element has more than one class?

Comment: For multiple classes: `className.indexOf('class') > 0`

Comment: `className.indexOf('class') > 0` would give false negatives with strings like "subclass".

Comment: No, and it was the point of my edit suggestion which you rejected.

Comment: @kats: I didn't reject any suggestion. This is a community edited site. If you want to improve this, let me know and I'll put it in myself (so that it doesn't have to go thru 2 edit approvals).

Comment: I see. The improvement is trivial: `var re = new RegExp('\\b' + className + '\\b'); for (/***/) { if (!re.test(input.className)) { /***/ } }`.

Comment: @kats: Updated my answer. I guess this makes my answer better than yours ;)

Comment: new RegExp('\\b' + 'nothis' + '\\b') is fail. Check: new RegExp('\\b' + 'nothis' + '\\b').test("class0 class2 class3 nothis-class4 class5") returns true. But must be returns false!

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
var _inputs = Array.prototype.filter.call(
                   document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
                   function(obj) { 
                     return obj.className.split(" ").indexOf("nothis")===-1;
                   });
```

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers you can do

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:not(.nothis)');
```