# getElementsByTagName Exclude Elements (Filter)

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript selector like this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

This works great except that I want to filter out some inputs (the ones with the class of "exists")

How can I do this without jQuery?

Comment: Iterate over the elements and put the ones you want to keep in an array. If [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) is available in the browsers your code is supposed to run, I'd rather use that.

Comment: @felix-kling I want something like this: var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input:not('.existent')"); I need to use this code on older browsers as well.

Comment: Yes, that won't work. That's why I said you have to iterate over the elements, test each of them if they have that class and if not, keep it (put it in an other array).

Comment: @Florescu, support CSS selectors, support older browsers, do not use jQuery. Choose any two.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi :) I don't use regular JavaScript that is why I am asking this question. With jQuery is simple $('inputs').not('.exists') and it will give me the array, but this script is done by someone else and I need to find a fix for this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS getElementsByTagName excep the one with a speciffic class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123004/js-getelementsbytagname-excep-the-one-with-a-speciffic-class)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var neededElements = [];
for (var i = 0, length = inputs.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].className.indexOf('exists') >= 0) {
        neededElements.push(inputs[i]);
    }
}
```

Or, in short (as provided by [knee-cola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268905/knee-cola) below):

```
let neededElements = [].filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input'), el => el.className.indexOf('exists') >= 0);
```

Comment: This can be made a bit shorter by using the filter function of the Array object: For example: `let neededElements = [].filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input'), el => el.className.indexOf('exists') >= 0);`.